# An alternative of "What is the impact of"

Tags: word-choice, questions

I am writing my thesis and I have been using the question `What is the impact of X on Y?` quite a lot. As an alternative, I change the word `impact` to `effect`, which is still the same.

Is there any alternative question to ask about the effect of something on another thing. For example, The effect of using the genetic algorithm on the network design.

Comment: *result, consequence, outcome, ramification(s), repercussion(s), upshot,...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What implications does `x` have on `y`. This is another one. Therefore, you could say something like: `What implications do genetic algorithms have on network design.`.